# How to reload content of DIV of Main HTML page from link inside the child HTML inside the main HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

My requirement: main HTML page which loads information from DB after login.
it will have tabs according to User's credentials.
so I have divided the display into 2 parts, the top half and tab part which is loaded into a DIV. 
tab part is loaded successfully after login. Now my question is if I want to show more information displayed as hyperlinks in the same DIV section, which should basically load another html file in place of the TAB html. how can I achieve this? I am currently stuck on how to proceed.

Snippets of my codes:-
Main HTML(this piece works perfectly after login):-

```
    <script> 
    $(function() {
    $("#includeContent").load("Viewport_initialLogin.html"); 
    }); 
    </script>
    <div id ="includeContent"></div>
```

Viewport_initialLogin.html file(works fine during login):-

```
    <script> 
    $(function() {
    $("#includeHomeContent").load("HomeInformation.html"); 
    $("#includePerfContent").load("PerformancePage.html");
    $("#includeAdminContent").load("AdminPage.html");
    $("#includeMaintContent").load("MaintenancePage.html");
    }); 
    </script>
```

HomeInformation.html file:-

(This file is basically content of the Tab page in my main HTML page and I have a link in this html file and once I choose the link, the DIV section in my main HTML file having id includeContent should be refreshed with another html file, so basically div having id includeContent should be refreshed with another html)..

My question is how can I achieve this, since the DIV id is in another HTML file?

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. However I do see you are struggling with view injections. So why don't you try Angularjs? Not sure if you're working on existing code or whatever. But it definitely seem you could use a JavaScript framework to help you with all the view injections you're trying to make.

Comment: Did you mean to include the contents of your HomeInformation.html file?